# Is there a number input field in flutter with increment/decrement buttons attached to the field?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to create a number input field with and up and down arrow button to increment and decrement its value. I am wondering if there is any inbuilt widget which already provides this functionality. I have to create couple of such fields in my UI and creating so many stateful widgets makes me wonder if there is any simpler approach.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Increment Decrement Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: NumberInputWithIncrementDecrement(),
    );
  }
}

class NumberInputWithIncrementDecrement extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NumberInputWithIncrementDecrementState createState() =>
      _NumberInputWithIncrementDecrementState();
}

class _NumberInputWithIncrementDecrementState
    extends State<NumberInputWithIncrementDecrement> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.text = "0"; // Setting the initial value for the field.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Number Field increment decrement'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                    decimal: false, signed: false),
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  minWidth: 5.0,
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up),
                  onPressed: () {
                    int currentValue = int.parse(_controller.text);
                    setState(() {
                      currentValue++;
                      _controller.text =
                          (currentValue).toString(); // incrementing value
                    });
                  },
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  minWidth: 5.0,
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                  onPressed: () {
                    int currentValue = int.parse(_controller.text);
                    setState(() {
                      print("Setting state");
                      currentValue--;
                      _controller.text =
                          (currentValue).toString(); // decrementing value
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 2,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

current output looks some thing like this.

[image]

I am looking for something like the following in a simpler manner like in HTML number input field.

[image]

Comment: Not built-in, but somebody had the same need as you and decided to create its own implementation. Check it out https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker

Comment: @haroldolivieri Thank you for the suggestion. In my case I am trying to use it in a Flutter_web project and the use case needs this increment in a quick manner like clicking a button and not like picking one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have laid out my Number input widget as shown below. I think I will go ahead with this approach until someone has any different idea for the same.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Increment Decrement Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: NumberInputWithIncrementDecrement(),
    );
  }
}

class NumberInputWithIncrementDecrement extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NumberInputWithIncrementDecrementState createState() =>
      _NumberInputWithIncrementDecrementState();
}

class _NumberInputWithIncrementDecrementState
    extends State<NumberInputWithIncrementDecrement> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.text = "0"; // Setting the initial value for the field.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Number Field increment decrement'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 60.0,
            foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                width: 2.0,
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    controller: _controller,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                      decimal: false,
                      signed: true,
                    ),
                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                      WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 38.0,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(
                              width: 0.5,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: InkWell(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                            size: 18.0,
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            int currentValue = int.parse(_controller.text);
                            setState(() {
                              currentValue++;
                              _controller.text = (currentValue)
                                  .toString(); // incrementing value
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                          size: 18.0,
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          int currentValue = int.parse(_controller.text);
                          setState(() {
                            print("Setting state");
                            currentValue--;
                            _controller.text =
                                (currentValue > 0 ? currentValue : 0)
                                    .toString(); // decrementing value
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:**

> As I see many of us like this approach I created a package for the same. Maybe its helpful for some of us.
> [number_inc_dec](https://pub.dev/packages/number_inc_dec)

Comment: Hi thank you so much! I think you should make this a package!

Comment: The latest Flutter 1.21.0-9.0.pre • channel dev requires that you replace `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly` with `FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly`

Comment: I will create an issue for this.

Comment: Also found this similar flutter widget https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_touch_spin - though it doesn't allow direct textfield editing.

Answer (score 21):

I was looking for a simple -/+ step counter, so I made one... don't pretend too much, I'm using flutter since a couple of days :-)

It has a maximum and minimum value, by default the minimum is set to zero and maximum to 10, but if you need negative values, just set it to -N.

### Preview

[image]

### Widget source

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NumericStepButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final int minValue;
  final int maxValue;

  final ValueChanged<int> onChanged;

  NumericStepButton(
      {Key key, this.minValue = 0, this.maxValue = 10, this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NumericStepButton> createState() {
    return _NumericStepButtonState();
  }
}

class _NumericStepButtonState extends State<NumericStepButton> {

  int counter= 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.remove,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 18.0),
            iconSize: 32.0,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (counter > widget.minValue) {
                  counter--;
                }
                widget.onChanged(counter);
              });
            },
          ),
          Text(
            '$counter',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black87,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 18.0),
            iconSize: 32.0,
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (counter < widget.maxValue) {
                  counter++;
                }
                widget.onChanged(counter);
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Read the counter value

```dart
...

int yourLocalVariable = 0;

...

     return Container(
              child: NumericStepButton(
                maxValue: 20,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  yourLocalVariable = value;
                },
              ),
            )
              
],
...
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Please Can you tell us how can we set initial value to 1?

Comment: @CihanKalmaz I don't remember now, probably you just need to pass minValue option set as "1". If you need the counter to reach a min value of 0, then set the initial value you need directly in the variable linked to the counter's value. Cheers

Comment: What if you need an initial value other than 0?

Comment: You can see how min/max values are handled in `_NumericStepButtonState`: what about  `counter = widget.initialValue` before `return Container(` ? I cannot test the solution in this moment, sorry

Answer (score 8):

[image]

This is the most complete solution you can find

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class NumberTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController? controller;
  final FocusNode? focusNode;
  final int min;
  final int max;
  final int step;
  final double arrowsWidth;
  final double arrowsHeight;
  final EdgeInsets contentPadding;
  final double borderWidth;
  final ValueChanged<int?>? onChanged;

  const NumberTextField({
    Key? key,
    this.controller,
    this.focusNode,
    this.min = 0,
    this.max = 999,
    this.step = 1,
    this.arrowsWidth = 24,
    this.arrowsHeight = kMinInteractiveDimension,
    this.contentPadding = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
    this.borderWidth = 2,
    this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _NumberTextFieldState();
}

class _NumberTextFieldState extends State<NumberTextField> {
  late TextEditingController _controller;
  late FocusNode _focusNode;
  bool _canGoUp = false;
  bool _canGoDown = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = widget.controller ?? TextEditingController();
    _focusNode = widget.focusNode ?? FocusNode();
    _updateArrows(int.tryParse(_controller.text));
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant NumberTextField oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _controller = widget.controller ?? _controller;
    _focusNode = widget.focusNode ?? _focusNode;
    _updateArrows(int.tryParse(_controller.text));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => TextField(
      controller: _controller,
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      maxLength: widget.max.toString().length + (widget.min.isNegative ? 1 : 0),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          counterText: '',
          isDense: true,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
          contentPadding: widget.contentPadding.copyWith(right: 0),
          suffixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: widget.arrowsHeight, maxWidth: widget.arrowsWidth + widget.contentPadding.right),
          suffixIcon: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(widget.borderWidth), bottomRight: Radius.circular(widget.borderWidth))),
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: widget.borderWidth,
                  right: widget.borderWidth,
                  bottom: widget.borderWidth,
                  left: widget.contentPadding.right),
              child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Material(
                        type: MaterialType.transparency,
                        child: InkWell(
                            child: Opacity(opacity: _canGoUp ? 1 : .5, child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up)),
                            onTap: _canGoUp ? () => _update(true) : null))),
                Expanded(
                    child: Material(
                        type: MaterialType.transparency,
                        child: InkWell(
                            child: Opacity(opacity: _canGoDown ? 1 : .5, child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)),
                            onTap: _canGoDown ? () => _update(false) : null))),
              ]))),
      maxLines: 1,
      onChanged: (value) {
        final intValue = int.tryParse(value);
        widget.onChanged?.call(intValue);
        _updateArrows(intValue);
      },
      inputFormatters: [_NumberTextInputFormatter(widget.min, widget.max)]);

  void _update(bool up) {
    var intValue = int.tryParse(_controller.text);
    intValue == null ? intValue = 0 : intValue += up ? widget.step : -widget.step;
    _controller.text = intValue.toString();
    _updateArrows(intValue);
    _focusNode.requestFocus();
  }

  void _updateArrows(int? value) {
    final canGoUp = value == null || value < widget.max;
    final canGoDown = value == null || value > widget.min;
    if (_canGoUp != canGoUp || _canGoDown != canGoDown)
      setState(() {
        _canGoUp = canGoUp;
        _canGoDown = canGoDown;
      });
  }
}

class _NumberTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  final int min;
  final int max;

  _NumberTextInputFormatter(this.min, this.max);

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (const ['-', ''].contains(newValue.text)) return newValue;
    final intValue = int.tryParse(newValue.text);
    if (intValue == null) return oldValue;
    if (intValue < min) return newValue.copyWith(text: min.toString());
    if (intValue > max) return newValue.copyWith(text: max.toString());
    return newValue.copyWith(text: intValue.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple, BLoC-friendly approach:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  final _streamController = StreamController<int>();

  StreamSubscription<int>? _subscription;

  Stream<int> get _stream => _streamController.stream;
  Sink<int> get _sink => _streamController.sink;

  int initValue = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _sink.add(initValue);
    _subscription = _stream.listen((event) => _controller.text = event.toString());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _sink.add(--initValue);
                    },
                    child: const Icon(Icons.remove)),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _sink.add(++initValue);
                    },
                    child: const Icon(Icons.add)),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    _streamController.close();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to call `_controller.text = event.toString()` outside of `setState()`?

Comment: @DurandA yep, there's EditableText stateful widget under the hood which listens to the controller value changes and calls setState when you type a symbol.