# can't use input field in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I can not use text fields of a flutter but buttons can work if I give any defined values.

Output Image with Input Field:
[image: screenshot]

```
children: <Widget>[
    Text(
        'Output : $sum',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
    TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter 1st number'),
        controller: t1,
    ),
    TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter 2nd number'),
        controller: t2,
    ),
```

Comment: Hello Mayur, I think you should see flutter doc for further web developement.Because nowadays flutter web is not for a production use. so after first release of web you can use flutter web. till please bear with us.

Comment: Hi Mayur, I am quite sure text inputs work in flutter web. I even posted a working code in another issue. You can check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914542/is-there-a-number-input-field-in-flutter-with-increment-decrement-buttons-attach). Can you explain what is not working..?

Comment: So, it doesn't exist eny input field?