# Cart Quantity selection with TextField Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to add text field in flutter and when user add value quatity value should be updated you can see in that below item image there is quantity I want to add a text field against it so user can edit quantity as much as he wanted to add you can ask anything you want to ask
[image]

here is the quantity selection

```
class QuantitySelection extends StatelessWidget {
  final int limitSelectQuantity;
  final int value;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Function onChanged;
  final Color color;

  QuantitySelection(
      {@required this.value,
      this.width = 40.0,
      this.height = 42.0,
      this.limitSelectQuantity = 100,
      @required this.color,
      this.onChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (onChanged != null) {
          showOptions(context);
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: kGrey200),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
        ),
        height: height,
        width: width,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 2.0, horizontal: (onChanged != null) ? 5.0 : 10.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    value.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: color),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (onChanged != null)
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 5.0,
                ),
              if (onChanged != null)
                Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                    size: 14, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showOptions(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      for (int option = 1;
                          option <= limitSelectQuantity;
                          option++)
                        ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                              onChanged(option);
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            title: Text(
                              option.toString(),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 1,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: kGrey200),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  S.of(context).selectTheQuantity,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

here is shopping cart

```
    class ShoppingCartRow extends StatelessWidget {
  ShoppingCartRow(
      {@required this.product,
      @required this.quantity,
      this.onRemove,
      this.onChangeQuantity,
      this.variation});

  final Product product;
  final ProductVariation variation;
  final int quantity;
  final Function onChangeQuantity;
  final VoidCallback onRemove;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String currency = Provider.of<AppModel>(context).currency;
    final currencyRate = Provider.of<AppModel>(context).currencyRate;

    final price = Services()
        .widget
        .getPriceItemInCart(product, variation, currencyRate, currency);
    final imageFeature = variation != null && variation.imageFeature != null
        ? variation.imageFeature
        : product.imageFeature;
    int maxQuantity = kCartDetail['maxAllowQuantity'] ?? 100;
    int totalQuantity = variation != null
        ? (variation.stockQuantity ?? maxQuantity)
        : (product.stockQuantity ?? maxQuantity);
    int limitQuantity =
        totalQuantity > maxQuantity ? maxQuantity : totalQuantity;

    ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Column(children: [
          Row(
            key: ValueKey(product.id),
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              if (onRemove != null)
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
                  onPressed: onRemove,
                ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Stack(children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                            width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.25,
                            height: constraints.maxWidth * 0.3,
                            child: Tools.image(url: imageFeature)),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 0,
                          right: 0,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: kGrey200),
                              color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(2.0)),
                            ),
                            child: QuantitySelection(
                              width: 60,
                              height: 32,
                              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                              limitSelectQuantity: limitQuantity,
                              value: quantity,
                              onChanged: onChangeQuantity,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ]),
                      SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(

                      ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          height: constraints.maxWidth * 0.3,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                product.name,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: theme.accentColor,
                                ),
                                maxLines: 4,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 7),
                              Text(
                                price,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: theme.accentColor, fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 10),
                              variation != null
                                  ? Services()
                                      .widget
                                      .renderVariantCartItem(variation)
                                  : Container(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          Divider(color: kGrey200, height: 1),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        ]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific, Your question is unclear, Which textfield you want to update and when.

Comment: you can see in that below item image there is quantity I want to add a text field against it so user can edit quantity as much as he wanted to add

Comment: You can use the `TextField` widget to create a text field (see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html). Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: This might be the answer you are asking: [Flutter dropdown text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49780858/flutter-dropdown-text-field/56170945)

Comment: @spkersten I know about the text field but I want to add text field and button to the right side of dropdown how to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think having an editable number field with plus and minus button would be a nice and user-friendly solution. There's a number of ways to do this with flutter - check out the solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914542/is-there-a-number-input-field-in-flutter-with-increment-decrement-buttons-attach) for ideas.